# Пытаюсь сверстать макет пиксель в пиксель и не поподаю в текст

Tags: html, css

Мне говорят , что это нормально и в текст попасть невозможно(ну во многих случаях)...тип юзаю пиксель перфект и смотрю и понимаю как бы не крутил не могу попасть в текст ,буквы... это нормально? вроде идет предложения и я попал в первое слово , а дальше всё равно разъезжается .

Comment: Правильно Вам сказали, невозможно попасть пиксель в пиксель

Comment: спасибо, а то я просто уже весь на нервах сегодня. В первый раз просто верстаю по макету и вот как то так...Кстатии , а бустрап вместе с медия использовать можно ?

Comment: Можно всё, что угодно, друг мой. Вопрос: правильно ли?

Comment: ну просто с бустрапом не получается пиксель в пиксель вообще , но о адаптивности не надо думать, уже всё сделано, но когда убираешь бустрап то пиксель в пиксель почти , но  в это же время адаптивность пропадает ...вот и возник такой вопрос

Comment: В 2019 году щас все отходят от стандарта "пиксель перфект", но это не повод менять верстку координально, на пару пикселей уж можно ошибиться, ничего страшного не будет, клиент не сожрёт, работодатель не убьёт.

Comment: насчет второго не уверен ...

Comment: такому заказчику вставляйте текст картинкой =)

Comment: оффигенная идея :D

Comment: идея из 90х всегда так делали

Comment: воспользуюсь :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, не будем забывать, что дизайнер работает не с голым шрифтом, как мы, а еще ко всему прочему имеет возможность менять ширину, вытянутость, межбуквенные интервалы и тд. Плюс ко всему мало какой дизайнер имеет представление о верстке шире чем обще-обывательское, из-за чего может вообще не парясь играться со шрифтом, как ему больше нравится, не думая о реализации. Так что ничего удивительно, что шрифты не попадают пиксель в пиксель. Не парься, а если чувствуешь, что заказчик педант конченный - есть средства в css для растягивания букв и тд, вроде даже интервалы задать можно, хотя врать не стану, ибо давно все это было и я уже забыл. В общем надеюсь помог или хотя-бы натолкнул на путь решения.

Comment: помогли))) я хотя бы понял что нереально (во многих случаях ) пиксель в пиксель )))